# How to unscope Devise queries when finding user on database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Anyone know how to unscope Devise queries when (authenticating or verifying) user in each request?

Let's say I have this User model with scope

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(group_id: 1)
end
```

I already got to unscope when authenticating, overriding the `find_for_authentication` devise method:

```
def self.find_for_authentication(conditions)
  User.unscoped { super }
end
```

But when I go to any page that has the `:authenticate_user!` filter, devise logs out the user because it's using the scope. I also tried to unscope the `active_for_authentication?` method, but it didn't work.

Does someone know where Devise fetch the current user from database in each request to a page that is filtered by `:authenticate_user!`?

I'm using Rails 3.2.1 and Devise 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `current_user` method in your `application_controller.rb` file:

```
def current_user
  User.unscoped { super }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.serialize_from_session(key, salt)
    self.unscoped { super }
  end
end
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24990576/464685